Automating My Device Without Software
I am in the early stages of designing a circuit, but there are some large holes in my knowledge that I was looking for some help with. I am designing the control circuit for a warming blanket I have been working on, but the challenge is that I must do it all in hardware.
Currently, I am using a waveform generator and SSR to deliver the power in bursts. At first I set the duty cycle to 100% (High Power[HP]) until it gets close to the set temperature and then I reduce the duty cycle (Low Power[LP]) to maintain the temperature. Assume the time to reach my desired temperature is known (and consistent) and so is the duty cycle for low power mode. My plan is to replace the waveform generator with a 555 chip. In order to do this I believe I would need 2 of these chips, one setup in monostable mode set for a certain amount of time and then another in astable mode fluctuating at the duty cycle needed for Low Power. I will have 3 separate temperatures, each with its own rise time and LP duty cycle, but the 3 circuits should be identical. The user would simply turn a switch and the device will take care of the rest.
My issues are:

Once the HP 555 chip is done how could I switch the SSR's input to the LP 555 chip?
Monostable mode requires a negative (0V) pulse to turn on. How can I do this if the user will only interact with a single rotary switch?
The rise time will be on the order of minutes, not seconds, so would a 555 chip be good to use for the HP section? If not, what other options could I use?

I am new to this, so any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

There are single-chip temperature controllers available, some of which require zero programming. Why would you try to make such a crude feed-forward-only control system when proper feedback control is probably actually simpler?

The goal was to save money by not using software, and this was where I ended up. I don't know what exists out there, so I came here in order to get help from others. Could you give me some ideas of chips to look into? I'm always open to new (and simpler) ideas.

If you want to save money, doing this with a $0.50 ATtiny or PIC12 would most likely be the cheapest option. Using a microcontroller is usually cheaper than achieving the same results without one.

What is the supply context of the blanket?

What do you mean by supply context? This is a new term for me.

There  is a good reason most controllers don't use '555 and multiple chips; it's more expensive than a microcontroller (8051-type chips under
a dollar).   But, your time-scale difference doesn't actually require a second chip, only a modulation of the current source  (usually a pull-up resistor).
What a mode change like that does require, is a temperature sensor and a 'high/low' distinction, which can be a temperature sense thermistor with (or without) an amplifier.
An operational amplifier, or comparator, can suffice to detect the
high/low status, and the output of that amplifier can modulate (steal
current from the '555 pull-up resistor) the duty cycle of the '555.
There's no need for switching two duty cycles, you could just proportion
the duty cycle smoothly over some temperature range.
Changing of the temperature target can be accomplished by changing the
sense circuit through the 'turn a switch' control (maybe with 'off' being
one of the control settings).
